# Javascript only runs when logged in as admin

Tags: users, navigation

I created a [test site](http://viawebservice03.europa-uni.de/?q=members/71%20). I put the JS into the template.php:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(".foomo").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, animated: true});});', 'inline');
```

File permissions are set [as described here](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924).

If I load the website as 'admin' the accordion is collapsed as I want.

But why doesn't open or close the accordion for any other user?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the views_accordion module, which works perfect:
[embedded views wrapped by views_accordion](http://viawebservice03.europa-uni.de/members/68)